# Cannot display google map route (API) with JQuery and html

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am try to populate google map route as [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/build-an-exercise-tracking-app-persistence-graphing/) tutorial says.
The map doesn't show and I started to investigate the source of the problem.
I can see that in the Add each GPS entry to an array, the output object looks like this:
[image]
I believe that it has something with the name of any object item (Every one of theme called 0).
Can someone tell me if it should be like this? and if not, what is the problem?

The Code (the relevance parts):

```
/*
 * Function that convert the objects into computed data 
 */
function get_total_km($object_key) {
    // Get all the GPS data for the specific workout
    var data = window.localStorage.getItem($object_key);
    // Turn the stringified GPS data back into a JS object
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    if (data) {
        // Calculate the total distance travelled
        total_km = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            if (i === (data.length - 1)) {
                break;
            }

            total_km += gps_distance(data[i].coords.latitude, data[i].coords.longitude, data[i + 1].coords.latitude, data[i + 1].coords.longitude);
        }

        total_km_rounded = parseFloat(total_km.toFixed(2));
        // Calculate the total time taken for the track
        start_time = new Date(data[0].timestamp).getTime();
        //Seperated start_time_public for returning object
        start_time_public = new Date(data[0].timestamp).getHours();
        date_id = new Date(data[0].timestamp).getDay();
        end_time = new Date(data[data.length - 1].timestamp).getTime();
        total_time_ms = end_time - start_time;
        total_time_s = total_time_ms / 1000;
        final_time_m = Math.floor(total_time_s / 60);
        final_time_s = Math.floor(total_time_s - (final_time_m * 60));
//        console.log({total_km_rounded: total_km_rounded, final_time_m: final_time_m, final_time_s: final_time_s});
        return ({total_km_rounded: total_km_rounded, final_time_m: final_time_m, final_time_s: final_time_s, date_id: date_id, start_time_public: start_time_public, data: data});
    }
}

                    // Set the initial Lat and Long of the Google Map
                    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(get_total_km(key).data[0].coords.latitude, get_total_km(key).data[0].coords.longitude);
                    // Google Map options
                    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 15,
                        center: myLatLng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    // Create the Google Map, set options
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

                    var trackCoords = [];
                    // Add each GPS entry to an array
                    for (ion = 1; ion < get_total_km(key).data.length; ion++) {
                        if (ion === (get_total_km(key).data.length - 1)){
                            break;
                        }
                        var dataa = get_total_km(key);
                        trackCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(dataa.data[ion].coords.latitude, dataa.data[ion].coords.longitude));
                    }
                    console.log(trackCoords);
                    // Plot the GPS entries as a line on the Google Map
                    var trackPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                        path: trackCoords,
                        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                        strokeWeight: 2
                    });
                    // Apply the line to the map
                    trackPath.setMap(map);
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a stupid problem...
The problem was that I accidentally named 2 divs with the same id name, and this has made the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your GPS object does not match to format, what expected in get_total_km function.

Your need to format GPS object to next format:

```
[
    {coords:{latitude:some, longitude:some}},  
    {coords:{latitude:some, longitude:some}}
]
```

Comment: I have changed to:                         trackCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng({coords:{latitude: dataa.data[ion].coords.latitude, longitude: dataa.data[ion].coords.longitude}}));
 and now the object structured but the Lat Lng are NULL..

Comment: [O, O, O, O, O, O, O, O, O, O, O]
0: O
nb: NaN
ob: NaN
__proto__: O
1: O
nb: NaN
ob: NaN
__proto__: O
2: O

Comment: when you call to get_total_km function, your GPS object must be already in required format, i.e. get_total_km([
    {coords:{latitude:some, longitude:some}},  
    {coords:{latitude:some, longitude:some}}
]);

Comment: I have try'd your answer but it is not working. this is my trackCode object now (I can see that in Google maps api this is the object structure i should have): [O, O, O, O, O, O, O, O, O, O, O, O]
0: O
nb: 45.427393662508806
ob: -121.72107615977819
__proto__: O
1: O
nb: 45.427393662508806
ob: -121.72107615977819
__proto__: O
2: O
3: O
4: O